# How to exclude Rampart module in service call

Tags: java, xml, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

We have a axis 2 service which calls  2  another service .For one service call ,we need rampart security .Hence we have configured that in our axis2.xml .However in the other service call ,I want to exclude rampart as no security is needed for that call .However since there is only 1 axis2.xml which is common ,therefore it is including rampart in both calls .How can I exclude this .

Answer (score 0):

You can add Rampart module at service service level or even at operation level e.g

```
<service name="name of the service" scope="name of the scope" class="full qualifide name the service lifecycle class"   targetNamespace="target namespase for the service">
    <Description> The description of the service  </Description>  
    <module ref="rampart" />

    <operation name="echoString" mep="operation MEP"> 
        <actionMapping>Mapping to action</actionMapping>
         <module ref="rampart" />
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
    </operation>
</service>
```

Axis 2 Configuration
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html#Service_Configuration

**For Client side**

The REPOSITORY_PATH should has a folder named 'modules' and the rampart mar should be inside this folder.

```
ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(REPOSITORY_PATH, null);
SimpleServiceStub stub = new SimpleServiceStub(ctx, "http://sbswsvm1426ou:9091/axis2/services/SimpleService?wsdl");
stub._getServiceClient().engageModule("rampart");
```

Comment: Thanks for the info .However I guess this will only reflect for the parent service operations and not the client service which I am calling .i.e in the services.xml ,I have all the operations that my service exposes .But I want to exclude rampart in the operation which is called from my service ...i.e the operation exposed by the external service .When I do it on axis2.xml level ,it is Global .